# Produce midi sound with rtMidi in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, midi

I have a problem playing a midi sound on my linux machine. Using RtMidi and C/C++ I generate three midi messages, and even though I try all the possible ports(I probed for all output ports) I cannot seem get a sound out of it. Should I manually connect one of these timidity ports to the speakers and how?

Thanks beforehand

EDIT 1:

I am trying to implement the solution by Chris Arndt described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330846/how-to-connect-to-alsa-server-in-this-case-timidity-in-ubuntu-using-c) as:

"Have a look at the RtMidi library. It is cross-platform (Win, OS X, Linux, SGI), written in C++ and easy to compile and include in your project.

Then start Timidity as a server (Ubuntu includes an init script for this), which will create several ALSA sequencer client ports for Timidity. Open one of these ports as an output in RtMidi and start sending midi messages."

Answer (score 0):

The problem derived from the online example of rtMidi, when I used the example from the documentation, it worked fine.

Comment: The MIDI output example on the RtMidi web page just opens the first available output, which, on Linux, is normally the MIDI through port, so the MIDI events would not reach Timidity. The 'midiout' example in the 'tests' directory of the RtMidi distribution has code for output port selection.